# How to remove all characters after the n first in a string dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-length

Let's take this simple dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Name=['abc','d',np.nan,'vbnc'],NoMatter=[0,6,2,3]))
   Name  NoMatter
0   abc         0
1     d         6
2   NaN         2
3  vbnc         3
```

I would like to remove in column Name all characters of the strings after the first two ones.

Expected output :

```
  Name  NoMatter
0   ab         0
1    d         6
2  NaN         2
3   vb         3
```

How please could I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['Name'] = df.Name.str[:2]
```

Output:

```
  Name  NoMatter
0   ab         0
1    d         6
2  NaN         2
3   vb         3
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way can be this as well:

```
df.Name = df.Name.apply(lambda x: x[:2] if not pd.isnull(x) else x)
```